# Why I am getting SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND error while I am executing following code section?

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, odbc

**CODE:**

This code runs successfully on a Windows machine. But it isn't working on a Linux machine. It does not perform any operation.

```
ret = SQLFetch(hstmt)
      if (ret == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
             ret = SQL_SUCCESS;
```

When I execute this code, I get the error `SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND`. Why am I getting this error? what is `SQLFetch()` and what is its functionality?

Comment: Maybe because there are no data in your database?

Comment: Perhaps your connection on Linux is broken.  You might want to include that relevant code.

Comment: what I should to rectify that connection problem @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Show us the code used to connect.  Maybe in the process you will see something wrong yourself.

Comment: Hmm ok . @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: [MSDN ODBC API doc of SQLFetch()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)